# How to correctly determine keyboard and text field position on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I want to lift the view when the keyboard shows and the text field becomes invisible. Here is my code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let tfPos = lastTextField!.convert(lastTextField!.frame, to: self.view)
        let tfBottom = tfPos.origin.y
        let kbTop = keyboardSize.origin.y

        if kbTop < tfBottom {
            self.verticalCenterConstraint.constant = -(tfBottom - kbTop)
        }
    }
}
```

I determine the top of the keyboard, then the bottom of the text field. However, the text field position is not correct as even if I can clearly see on the screen that it is above the keyboard, my code says it's below with 35pt. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you used `UIScrollView`?

Comment: No it’s not a ScrollView

Answer (score 2):

Step :- 1 Add Observer for the hide and show notifications

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), 
name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), 
name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

Step :- 2 Implement target method

```
@objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

if notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide {
    yourTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
} else {
    yourTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
}

yourTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = yourTextView.contentInset

let selectedRange = yourTextView.selectedRange
yourTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(selectedRange)
}
```

Comment: This answer was taken from Paul Hudson: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/16/7/fixing-the-keyboard-notificationcenter

Answer (score -1):

If any changes are done to the constraints self.view.layoutIfNeeded() needs to be called.
You can call it in animation block

UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                           delay: TimeInterval(0),
                           options: animationCurve,
                           animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                           completion: nil)

Comment: Nothing happens if I add this.